# how to remove all [d+] except the last [d+]?

Tags: ruby, regex

i have a string like

```
/root/children[2]/header[1]/something/some[4]/table/tr[1]/links/a/b
```

and

```
/root/children[2]/header[1]/something/some[4]/table/tr[2]
```

how can i reproduce the string so that all the `/\[\d+\]/` are removed except for the last `/\[\d+\]/` ?

so i should end up with .

```
/root/children/header/something/some/table/tr[1]/links/a/b
```

and

```
/root/children/header/something/some/table/tr[2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No loops for you. Use a lookahead assertion (?= ... ):

```
s.gsub(/\[\d+\](?=.*\[)/, "")
```

There's a reasonable explanation of the very useful lookaround operators [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Exactly. You posted this while I was typing the same solution, identical except you put a helpful space before the ""!

Comment: Oh, and I did the speed check, and this version is almost twice as fast as Pavel's while loop...

Comment: Nice one Glenn. It's an important space that one =P.

Comment: It should be `s.gsub!(/\[\d+\](?=.*\[\d+\])/, "")`.  Still twice faster?

Answer (score 1):

We will have to use `while` loop, I guess.  And here comes good ol' C-style-loop solution:

```
while s.gsub!(/(\[\d+\])(.*?)(\[\d+\])/, '\2\3'); end
```

It's a bit hard to read, so I'll explain.  The idea is that we match the string with a pattern that requires *two* `[\d+]` blocks to persist in a string.  In the replacement, we just delete the first one.  We repeat it until string doesn't match (so it contains only one such block) and utilize the fact that `gsub!` doesn't perform substitution when string is unmatched.

Comment: Cleaner than mine, and about 5% faster. +1

Comment: Just don't forget to put a comment on that puppy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm absolutely certain there's a more elegant solution, but this ought to get you going:

```
string = "/root/children[2]/header[1]/something/some[4]/table/tr[1]/links/a/b"
count = string.scan(/\[\d+\]/).size
index = 0
string.gsub(/\[\d+\]/) do |capture|
  index += 1
  index == count ? capture : ""
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str.scan(/\[\d+\]/)[0..-2].each {|match| str.sub!(match, '')}
```